# What are the pros and cons for using a database to store configuration information compared to a File System

Tags: java, sql, xml, relational-database, configuration-files

Suppose you are tasked with writing a web application that must store configuration information in some format. What are the benefits and drawbacks for storing these configuration information in a relational database compared to storing the information in a file? Configuration options may include but not limited to data retention  settings and settings for interfacing with external system (e.g. ip address, port, username, password).

Comment: you mean external systems with username and password like... a database?

Comment: @Pleun Yeah, bad idea I know, but it would be encrypted. Assume the existence of the password in the file is not a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a summary of pros and cons

Pros for file:

1. Fast access to configuration data.  (assuming no caching)
2. Each server can be configured differently (in a load balancing situation)
3. You already need a file for the database credentials so everything can be stored in one place.

Cons for file:

1. Configuration in a load balanced environment is difficult.
2. When adding settings under development, one most remember to move them into the files on every server in production.
3. Configuration must be writable by the webserver if you want to write a control panel to change the settings at runtime.  Manipulating files in a control panel is a hassle due to timing issues and or locking.

Pros for database:

1. Load balancer can share configuration across the cluster
2. It's very easy to check on settings remotely or change them such as in phpMyAdmin or a straight sql client.
3. Control panel development becomes simple.
4. Performance impact can be mitigated by caching configuration in memcached or in a hash in memory.
5. Programmers are more likely to control settings rather than IT people or at least can be controlled through control panel.

Cons for database:

1. Performance maybe slow if you're fetching the settings continuously.
2. If you don't provide a tool, it might be more difficult for sysadmins to administer the product rather than a file. They might not be sql gurus.
3. Clustering is more of a pain.

This comes down to personal preference and any current or possible future requirements for providing easy configuration.

Comment: 1 more Cons to Database is : Data type support for complex config properties and changes to such will be big headache if you are doing it in DB, as schema needs to be changed and associated overhead of migrating old data. However this is simple in XML as it supports free form data and not many constraints.

Answer (score 2):

And now a real answer.

I guess in the end it is a matter of taste

Pro:

- you could add an admin page to edit the settings in your applications

Con:

- if your database is not available, your settings are also gone
- if you migrate a database to a different environment (e.g. a production database to test to do some issue checking) your settings are included
- slightly harder to deploy
- more difficult to add to version control
- you need a file anyway to store your database credentials

Comment: 1. It's easier to add user-specific settings.
2. Can be seen by anyone who can run SQL; file systems are harder to share.  Getting a share in corpo-world can be tough.

Comment: @TonyEnnis: i do not consider user settings to be configuration information but 100% application data

Comment: I actually find it a lot easier to deploy. How do you add a single configuration setting to an existing text file without overwriting adjusted values? With a database it's a simple INSERT statement.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : you just add a line :)

Comment: If your database is not available, the settings still can be, if you periodically dump the settings to a human-readable and machine-parseable format (e.g. with mysqldump)

Comment: @gcbenison: yes, but your application will not read them unless you implement some fallback scenario

Answer (score 1):

Because then all you have to do is have your connection pool properly configured (which you should have to do anyway), and then you know where all of your settings are located. Plus they can be updated at runtime, they be updated with the app up or down, and they can't be stomped on with when the application is deployed.

All sorts of good reasons.